# no top plate on my stud wall - gap between boards goes up through ceiling to 1st floor

Tags: drywall, studs, load-bearing, partition

It seems like the stud wall I'd planned to remove to make an open plan lounge/kitchen in my 30 yr old house is not the frame structure I'd expected.  I removed a bit of the dry wall on one side to find the top plate but there's no top plate - just a gap between the dry wall either side of the frame that seems to continue up into a 1st floor wall that is above maybe half of the width of the ground floor wall. About a third of the width of the ground floor wall then runs under the staircase.  I want to remove the whole ground floor wall and if it was a regular stud frame wall I would have done so but now I'm concerned it may be an issue because I don't recognise this design??

It surely can't be a load bearing wall - it runs parallel to the ceiling joists above and as mentioned the stairs are over about a third of the wall (and it has a doorway in the middle of it).  The survey mentioned standard stud walls and didn't comment that any were load bearing.  Does this sound like I can safely remove it and block up/plaster the gap??!  Is it a standard design for a non load bearing stud wall?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you post some pictures.  30 years is not that old for building designs, maybe go back 100 years or more.

Comment: It is probably not load bearing because of running parallel to the joists.  All walls need to sit on something, usually a floor, so you won't be able to just cut the studs part way up and leave them hanging in the air.  It does seem strange to have long studs, which is why pictures are so important.

Comment: Apologies for the pics not being ideal but the day after I bought the house & pulled out the old kitchen units ready to fit my new Ikea kitchen I slipped and broke my wrist!!!  So the pics are by my friend who was at the house today & were the best I could him to send (language problems too!)!  I'll try & get there tomorrow and take some up inside the hole but maybe these may help in the meantime?

Comment: When I put my hand in the hole & up toward the ceiling it was hollow & the dry wall boards went right up into the 1st floor wall.

Comment: It really does look unusual, but I would have a concern that although the studs might not be supporting a floor load, it may be supporting the wall above.

Comment: Sounds like balloon framing. Locally, that's not done any more due to poor fire performance (good for the fire, bad for the house and occupants.)

Comment: Yes, that was my concern...I wondered if there was any other reason that the dry wall boards would continue up into the wall above - but is it standard for the whole rest of the wood frame that the 1st floor boards are fixed to to just rest on the downstairs frame?  Sounds like I maybe need a builder to check it at the very least...

Comment: And balloon framing sounds worrying - I'm gonna google it now!

Comment: It sounds like balloon framing, but I doubt it in a 30 year old(almost new) house(unless the builder was a weirdo).  Pictures and more exploring is needed, might just be missing something.

Comment: Either balloon framing or the ceiling was dropped for some reason at one time and the original ceiling is up higher

Comment: Jack may have nailed it with a drop ceiling instead of balloon framing. You use "ground floor" and "first floor" indicating you're not in the US, please let us know where in the world you are as building standards are different. Also, insert a measuring tape into the hole to see how far up you can push it. If it only goes a few inches to a foot or so, I'd think Jack is spot on. If you can keep pushing and pushing, it might be balloon framing.

Comment: Brilliant comments, thank you Jack & FreeMan particularly - and yes, I'm in the uk...my usual stack questions are coding ones that don't really change based on US/UK.  That's why I was puzzled when I googled 'balloon framingf; as it seemed to be the US/Canada it was mainly used in - and certainly not 30 yrs ago.  I have a builder coming later today to check it and I will do the tape test when I go to meet him (haven't moved in yet!)and post back here later, but thank you all so much for helping me....

Comment: ...and it really could be that the original ceiling has been lowered because it's been covered with textured plaster which the seller loved and has everywhere so it may have a false ceiling to facilitate that I guesss...but I will check that today and really hope that's what it is...!

Answer (score 2):

OK, well my builder finally solved the riddle!  I had already found a thin 'top plate' just above the level of the ceiling when he arrived so it could be as Jack said that it was a false ceiling, but apparently this is a 'Paramount' wall!!!  No wood frame, or just very thin wood pieces between the panels if anything, and a cardboard 'eggbox' structure between the drywall panels for strengthening(!)  Notoriously easy to knock a hole in,  & my builder says they are put in after the floor & ceiling and are NOT loadbearing!  So lump hammers are out tonight!!!  (Sorry I didn't get any more photos but I really didnt want to go  up a ladder with a camera & a broken wrist in a sling...)

Thank you all for helping to point me in the right direction and I hope this conversation helps someone in the future.... :-)

Comment: I did lots of searching on a "paramount" wall, kept getting the movie company. :) For future web-searchers, they're apparently also called "eggbox" walls.